# MySQL query that can get distinct ids for logins and how many there were

Tags: mysql

I have a database that gets a new row added for every time a user logs into the system. What I would like to be able to do is first to make a query that gets the distinct entries by the hashed user ids. This I can do. SELECT DISTINCT is our friend it seems. After this, however, I would still like to be able to get a count, per user id, of how many times people logged in.

For instance, if Max logged in 3 times and Sally logged in 2 times I would have five rows in my DB. After running SELECT DISTINCT by their user ids it would just give me one Max and one Sally user id. After having this information, however, I'd like to be able to create a hash, map, whatever, that stores the following information:

Max => 3

Sally => 2

Is there a way using pure, or mostly pure, SQL that this could be achieved in an efficient manner or should I simply get out ALL of the login db rows and search and compile the information myself. I know I could do it this way but *somehow* that feels slower. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in SQL using the "GROUP BY" operator.  For example:

```
SELECT user_id, count(*) FROM USERS GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT username,COUNT(*) AS LoginCount FROM logintable GROUP BY username`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT login, COUNT(login) FROM yourtable GROUP BY login
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure...

select
   hashed_user_id, count(*)
from
   table name
group by hashed_user_id

Answer (score 0):

the answer could be more specific if you give tabl structure:

however, this is typically an aggregate function with a group by - something like this:

```
select user, count(user)
from access_log
group by user
```

Answer (score -1):

Trying to do a count like you're saying is an unecessary overhead. My advice would be to add an extra field in your users table 'logincount' and +1 every time a user logs in. Much quicker.